# Receiving click/swipe events on a view behind a transparent item of a listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a layout similar to Foursquare [(image)](http://www.blogcdn.com/www.engadget.com/media/2013/03/foursquare-android-nearby.jpg), where a `View` (in their case, a map) is behind a `ListView`, but is visible because the first element  is transparent.

I need the `View` behind the `ListView` to take touch and swipe events. Is there a way to make *only* that first invisible item of the `ListView` ignore these events and allow the events to propagate to the `View` behind it, but have the rest of the `ListView` items take the events as usual?

I'm just hoping I won't have to completely abandon the `ListView` and use a `ScrollView` instead, because I've already implemented a lot of `ListView` specific features.

Comment: If you use frameLayout it should already ignore the events unless you specify otherwise. Try this, frame layout with 3 layouts inside. Top(menu/list ~~half screen) Mid (transparent ~~ full screen) Bottom(full screen map).

Comment: Doesn't the list also need to be full screen? Otherwise when you scroll up, it won't look like it's covering the map. It'll just be a normal list view covering half the map at all times

Comment: Yes you are right. I will post some code.

Comment: I'm doing the same kind of UI, also inspired in foursquare. Did you solve this problem? Because I'm stuck in the very same issue.

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView on the back will work normaly unless you click the button:

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ScrollView 
                android:id="@+id/bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:text="asdfasdfa Put more text for testing sdfasdfasdfasdfasdfff
                afdasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf
                asdfasdfa"/>
        </ScrollView>
        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/top"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/butt"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:text="Test"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Both of the layers/frames have height and width set to `match_parent` (full screen in this case). And you can basicaly put anything you want into both of this layers as you need it.

Comment: Sorry, that still isn't what I needed. I decided to implement a OnTouchEvent that transforms the listview up and down.

Comment: @eugeneration No need to be sorry :) You should do what ever works for you. Good luck.